# MySQL query returns wrong result count between a date range

Tags: mysql, date

I have created a query which returns results between a date range, however the previous developer has shoot me on the foot by saving the date as a `varchar(10)` in MySQL and also in two formats (`Y-m-d` and `d-m-Y`).

My problem is that when I select results between a date from **`01-June-2015`** to **`11-June-2015`**, it gave me **`18`** results for **`June 2015`**.

But when I select results between a date from **`01-june-2014`** to **`11-June-2015`**, it gave me **`13`** results for **`June 2015`** which must be **`18`** results, I think.

**TASK: GET TOTAL OF NEW VISITORS IN A DATE RANGE BUT DATE IS NOT PRESENT IN VISITOR TABLE SO I TAKE HIS VERY FIRST VISIT DATE FROM VISIT TABLE That's why I use `MIN()` function**

MySQL query is:

```
SELECT min(visits.id), t.id, t.first_name,
    visits.date_check_in
FROM `visitor` `t`
    JOIN `visit` `visits` ON visits.visitor = t.id
WHERE 
  ((STR_TO_DATE(visits.date_check_in, '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN
    STR_TO_DATE('11-06-2014', '%d-%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('11-06-2015',
    '%d-%m-%Y')) 
OR (STR_TO_DATE(visits.date_check_in, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN
    STR_TO_DATE('2014-06-11', '%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('2015-06-11',
    '%Y-%m-%d')) ) 
AND (t.is_deleted = 0) 
AND (visits.is_deleted = 0)
AND (visits.visit_status != 2)
GROUP BY `t`.`id`
```

kindly help me what am I doing wrong. I have spent about 4 days by thinking and doing different things but got stuck. 
I hope to hear from you quickly, thanks.

Comment: I suggest you to correct the table by changing date format to MySQL date format. You can write PHP script to update the date by using that table primary key. So that It will solve this kind unexpected result.

Comment: Dear, its a big web dashboard and these dates have been used in about 6 to 7 places for insertions,updation and reporting which require more effort to correct those everywhere.

Comment: if you use aggreagate functions you must to group by over all selected columns. in mysql its not needed but then you get unexpected results

Comment: not working by grouping on all columns

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is find out, if date format is not `Y-m-d`. If format is `d-m-Y`, change it to `Y-m-d`, and then compare it, like:

```sql
WHERE
    IF(SUBSTRING(visits.date_check_in, 5, 1) = '-', 
        visits.date_check_in, 
        STR_TO_DATE(visits.date_check_in, '%d-%m-%Y')
    ) BETWEEN '2014-06-11' AND '2015-06-11'
```